# Creating model for unordered list in Django

Tags: python, django, model

What is the best approach to create a model field in Django, so that in template, I can iterate over its objects as:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in ModelName.fieldname %}
        <li>{{ item }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

so It output something like, lets say:

```
<h1>Apple Products</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Ipod</li>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Ipod mini</li>
  <li>Display XDR</li>
  <li>Macbook Pro</li>
</ul>
```

My thoughts:

- Create a separate model and then reference it as foreign key to parent model.
- create a `CharField` and separate each list item with comma, then create a function; return a `list` and loop over `list` of separated items by comma.

Kindly share your idea, what is better approach and professional way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: The first one. Definitely the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go >>>>In **models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
   name  = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)

class Product(models.Model):
  name       = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
  category   = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

In your **views.py**::

```
def myView(request):
   my_list = []
   all_prd = Product.objects.all()
   all_cat = Category.objects.all()
   for cat in all_cat:
      temp = list(all_prd.objects.filter(category__name = cat ))
      my_list.append(temp)
   my_list = list(filter(None, my_list)
   context = [
      'my_list' : my_list,
   ]
   return(request, 'cute.html' , context)
```

In **cute.html** ::

```
<ul>
   {% for item in my_list %}
       {% for prd in item %}
          {{prd.name}}
       {% endfor %}
      <br>
      <br>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**I gave you a hint.modify it like you want.**

Comment: That view is pretty darn inefficient, FWIW…

Comment: please explain!

Comment: You're reading the entire database into memory, using many separate queries. You can get the same effect pretty much with `context = {'my_list': Product.objects.all().order_by('category')}`, and then loop over that in the view, which will get each row one by one without storing them in memory.

Comment: lets say there are additional sub-categories.what to do then?

Comment: Then you come up with another query that suits your purpose. You could iterate `Category.objects.all()` ordered by some criteria, and [prefetch related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) products, which would still be more efficient than what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you very much for correction.i will try to do following.

Comment: one ques, does it take more time to render html in my way??

Comment: Yes, it takes time before the rendering of the HTML starts, because you're doing a lot of work before that. You should preferably always just pass a `QuerySet` (e.g. `Category.objects.all()`) to your template and iterate it there, instead of stuffing it into a list first.